# Converting document from letter to a4 paper size

Tags: paper-size

A document is typed with default letter size. I want to take printout on a4 size. Everything gets disturbed on printed pages. I tried manually changing margins, font-size, horizontal spacing, vertical spacing etc. Is there an easier solution?  I mean everything gets fitted in symmetric manner from letter size to a4 (something similar image getting resized from diagonals in symmetric way).

Comment: Was the document create with LaTeX? If yes, do you have the source `tex` file? If not, you can use the printer options to shrink it before printing.

Comment: Yes it was typed with latex. I have source tex file.

Comment: Use the `a4paper` option within the class. For example, `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}`.

Comment: It disturbs everything, for example tables go outside page right side. I have already completed typing in default letter size.

Comment: So you have to change only paper dimensions but keep text width and height the same. It is better to use `geometry` to do that. Delete the option from the class and try `\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=297mm]{geometry}`.

Comment: effect is same....it is of no use...

Comment: You need to provide an example that shows the problem, the default `\textwidth` that latex uses for letter fits easily on an A4 page.

Answer (score 5):

Use `letterpaper` as option (it's the default) and change the physical page parameters after the computations are made.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\pdfpageheight=297mm
\pdfpagewidth=210mm
\pdfhorigin=\dimexpr1in+(210mm-8.5in)/2\relax
\pdfvorigin=\dimexpr1in+(297mm-11in)/2\relax

\begin{document}
\kant
\end{document}
```

The first 1in is the normal offset applied by TeX; we shift the origin by the difference between the dimension of A4 paper and of Letter paper, divided by 2.

This should work with any document class.

[image]

Comment: I can't find kantlipsum package in miktex 2.9 package manager running on windows.

Comment: @chetan Complain fiercely!!! For testing, just do `\usepackage{lipsum}` in the preamble and `\lipsum[1-12]` instead of `\kant`.

Comment: @chetan That's ridiculous: MiKTeX does not support `\kant`? Maybe you are mistaking a mere appearance of MiKTeX for the real thing?

Answer (score 3):

The `paper` and `layout` options of `geometry` are designed for this. By default, `layout` is set to match `paper` since that is, typically, what you want. However, it can be easily overridden:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,layout=letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
    \kant[1-10]
\end{document}
```

The first word on the third page is 'apperception' which is also the first word on the third page if I pass no options to `geometry` so that it defaults to `letterpaper`. [`geometry` rather inconsiderately and, in my view, improperly overrides the default paper setting for the system.]

Layout on default letter-sized paper:

[image: letterpaper]

Layout on A4 with above settings:

[image: letterpaper on A4]

Comment: Cfr, this is not good if one ues \usepackage[paper=a5paper,layout=letterpaper]{geometry}

Comment: @touhami Why would you use that if you want to have layout for letter paper on A4 paper? Probably I'm missing something but that just seems irrelevant to the question. That is, you're right in the sense that what you say is true. But what you say seems not to bear any relation to the question. Note that the same objection applies to egreg's answer....

Comment: Cfr, you are right and i had upvote your answer before comment it, but as you say i am still right in the sense that the solution is not general and others should know that. Otherwise  your solution is very elegant (may be that's why i comment it)

Comment: @touhami Well, I don't think *any* solution will work for going from letter paper to A5 which also works for the OP's situation, because anything designed to keep the layout fixed (required for this question) will be unusable in the case of letter to A5. You can't just scale a letter down by 50% or so and think that the results will be acceptable. And I'm assuming that nobody would reasonably want to. Of course, I don't deny that your solution is technically general in a way that mine is not. But I don't see any practical difference. (And I am wary of scaling text at all, as your answer does.)

Comment: Ok, again you are right.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can do this with pgfpages, add to preambul

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper]
```

Comment: Do you mean `pdfpages` as you first say or `pgfpages`, as your code suggests?

Comment: pgfpages. Try the code as it is. pdfpages can be a solution.

Comment: You might want to correct your introductory line, in that case, to avoid confusion.